# SQL String Parsing with Hashtags

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, reactjs

How do I extract #hashtags from texts saved in SQL? Or directly extract #hashtag and show them as clickables in search bar "drop-down like thing"?

For example

> text1 = "This is a nice #hashtag and I #like it"; => result =>
> #hashtag , #like
>
> text2 = "#hopefully I will get #answer #here"; => result => #hopefully
> #answer  #here

All these texts are in a SQL table and I forgot to make a column for hashtags which should store this data.
**OR**
The main Purpose is to extract these hashtags and show as user types relative words in search box
for e.g User types **#h**
he should see **#hashtag** (from text1 above example)
and           **#here**    (from text2 above example)
and           **#hopefully**    (from text2 above example)

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of hashtags like this:

```js
const sentence = "This is a nice #hashtag and I #like it"
const hashtags = sentence.split(" ").filter(word=> word.startsWith("#"))

console.log(hashtags)
```